# how to use nvl in pyspark for variable?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, hive

i have a scenario like getting the maximum date from the table in hive and if the table is empty then max(column) will be null/none in that scenario replace that with "2022-01-01"

i am getting the max from

df1 = spark.table()
max_date_to=df1.agg(max(col("date"))).collect()[0].asDict()['max(date)']

but my table is empty so i what to get the value as "2022-01-01"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could simply use `if else` in this scenario,

```
df1 = spark.table()
check_date = df1.agg(max(col("date"))).collect()[0].asDict()['max(date)']
# Check if the check_date variable is not null if yes then use as it is else use the other date.
max_date_to = check_date if check_date else "2022-01-01"
```

EDIT:

If you want to convert the string to datetime object do something like this,

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
max_date_to =  datetime.strptime(max_date_to, '%Y-%m-%d')
```

EDIT 2:
If you just want to add one day try this instead of Pyspark function,

```
max_date_from = max_date_to + timedelta(days=1)
```

Comment: Hi, can you help on how we can convert it into date format? as i have to do date+1 in the above and then store it into variable

Comment: You can use `strptime` to convert string into datetime object

Comment: i am using "max_date_from=date_add(to_date(max_from,"yyyy-mm-dd"),1)" but when i am printing the variable is am getting something like max_date_from:  Column<'date_add(to_date(2023-06-19, yyyy-mm-dd), 1)'>    any idea what i am doing wrong?

Comment: You need to collect it, pyspark is lazily evaluated so it will just create a plan for you and not execute until needed, so do something like, `max_date_from=date_add(to_date(max_from,"yyyy-mm-dd"),1).collect()`

Comment: Check EDIT 2 section

Comment: max_date_from=date_add(to_date(max_from,"yyyy-mm-dd"),1).collect() while using this facing error TypeError: 'Column' object is not callable and using max_date_from = max_date_to + datetime.timedelta(days=1) giving type object 'datetime.datetime' has no attribute 'timedelta'

Comment: check the edit section again